# Why the trench run and not divebomb the shaft?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope, death-star

In *A New Hope*  they needed to go through the trench. This meant they lost almost all of their maneuverabiltiy and were easy targets in there due to the narrow width of the trench itself.

Now I'm wondering...why did they do that and not fly just outside the trench and then dive bomb onto the shaft and torp it that way?

Is there any in universe reason? (out of universe I guess it was the rule of cool that succeeded there).

Comment: Didn't the trench provide cover from the majority of turbo laser cannons?

Comment: Wasn't the shaft horizontal?

Comment: @Paulie_D the shaft was vertical (at least on screen it always looked like that)

Comment: @Alith but you have to get to the trench first. They could enter the trench right next to the target, and get just as much cover. Space has three dimensions and the Death Star is a sphere.

Comment: Likely a duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/12129/74137